# Processing csv files (alternative to business logic in DB)

Tags: design, web-development, architecture, database, domain-driven-design

We are working on a fulfillment system for an online book store. Everyday we receive tens of CSV files (about 90 files) with data about purchased orders.
**Example:**

```
OrderId    |    BookTitle    |    Quantity    |    Price    |    BuyerName    |    ...
1          |The hunger games |        1       |     10      |    John Doe     |    ...
1          | The Exorcist    |        2       |     25      |    John Doe     |    ...
2          |   Superman      |        1       |     5.5     |    Jane Nose    |    ...
```

**What we currently do:**
The data need to be translated to our domain to `Order` entity, `OrderItem` entity,...etc. We load the file into dummy tables then use very complex queries to populate the `Orders` table and `OrderItems` table.

**Problem:**
 All the business logic is in the database (in the queries) so unit
   testing them is a nightmare. In addition we were requested to change the database we are using (not exactly, but something terrifyingly similar)

**What we tried:**
We are moving to a DDD approach where the domain model is the core of the application that holds all the logic and validation.

We tried to parse the file line by line and create the respective entities and validate them accordingly then save them to the database.
This resulted in thousands of calls to the database and sometimes the server runs out of memory coz of the thousands of records (around 90 thousand record/file) in a single file.

I know this domain is dead old and someone must have found a better way to handle such task. How do you process such huge files in your domain without suffering from performance?

UPDATE

- We are using a MySql database with PHP and Apache.
- The CSV file is loaded into a dummy table using something similar to this:

```sql
load data local infile 'orders.csv' into table dummyOrders fields terminated by ','
  enclosed by '"'
  lines terminated by '\n'
    (orderId, bookkTitle,Quantity, Price, BuyerName,...)
```

Comment: How are you inserting them in the database? Is this a execute statement x 1000? or a prepare x 1, execute x1000? or some form of [bulk data loading](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-speed.html)?

Comment: Hm, "thousands of records" in a single file, and "tens of files per day" - does not sound very huge for me. And only two tables to fill (Orders and OrderItems)? Does not sound very complex. The server runs out of memory? What kind of database server are you using? Maybe you just have to increase some transaction buffer sizes?

Comment: Your original approach seems preferable.  I sympathize with your desire to have unit tests and validation, but this is essentially an [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) scenario.

Comment: @MichaelT please check the update.

Comment: @DocBrown I updated the question with some numbers. We approximately receive 90 files per day and each file contains about 90 thousand records. Sometimes 200 records in during sales and Christmas. We have mainly 2 tables 2 fill in addition to 2 more for invalid orders and history requirements. We have very complex validation rules on the data. We need to combine elated records to common aggregates then validate again. Believe me it's a nightmare for maintenance. A change to the validation or any new requirement introduces numerous hard to detect bugs. I was hoping to use unit test, but in vain

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the ETL link. It seems we were doing just that without knowing!

Comment: Is the csv load that you mention the way that is running out of memory? or the way that is working currently?  If its the currently working way, whats the way you are running out of memory?

Comment: @MichaelT We are currently loading the file into the dummy table. This works fine for apache/php performance as the whole load is on the database itself to process the data. When we parse the file first using PHP to create our entities we run out of memory as the number of created object in enormous.

Comment: Ok, so its the process that distills the .csv in the temp file into its final destination that is running out of memory... why are you / do you need to instantiate all the objects? Does it even need to be object oriented? You're doing this batch processing (I assume) in php... why?

Comment: @MichaelT well the validation rules are many and change regularly. Sometimes it varies among different suppliers. We were hoping to encapsulate the rules into specifications to proper test them and change them easily. I don't know the alternative to not instantiate them all. Are you implying that I should create a unit of work maybe? like processing 100 lines then saving them then another batch?

Comment: @Songo that is a possibility.  Consider also if certain things can be done on everything in one pass (an update statement).  And while php [*can*](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-batch/) be used for batch processing, it probably isn't the best tool for that (though I'll admit that that statement is my personal opinion).

Comment: It also sounds like you need to change the commit frequency of your transactions (like every 100 or 1000 records inserted/updated). Your DBA should be able to help you tune that.

Comment: @MichaelT Yup using PHP also affected other normal users doing day to day tasks (Customer service, Operations,...etc). Processing in PHP even in batches took a long time and a huge memory specially since several files get processed simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

You were doing it right - load the file into a dummy table (preferably on a staging DB), then manipulate the data with stored procedures (which are easy to test - they're little more than a single function, and you can put test data in the tables and run your sprocs using that data in a transaction that can be rolled back so they can be very isolatable regardless of what data exists in there).

Once you have your data in a good state, you migrate it to the production DB. That one will not need to have all the loading SQL in it, so can be simpler to manage.

So basically, split your operations into 2, staging and production. I've used this approach with millions of records and very good performance (though with SqlServer, not MySQL).

Comment: +1 I never thought about splitting the process into 2 databases. Gonna talk with our database admin and see if that is feasible.

Comment: +1, though I think your remark about stored procedures is not precise. SP are not easier or as harder to test than most other code "per se". They probably can *be designed* to be easier to test than complex SQL queries.

Comment: @Songo: note that this gist of this answer is not primarily about using two databases - its about splitting the process into more intermediate steps (maybe two databases can help you to make this easier, but maybe some temporary tables are enough).

Comment: @DocBrown oh yes, sprocs aren't magic, but if you write a SP then it is contained in the DB and not spread over a load of files spaghetti-like. That's really what I meant. Also, if you've designed a system that uses them, you can mock them out in the business logic easier than if you have SQL embedded into your code.